# Unexpected styling and tag rendering in articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, styling

I've been using Joomla for a long time and the past 2 weeks i have had 2 articles act like they're haunted.

The first article won't recognize p or /p tags. It inserts them as text into the article instead of a page break.

The second article is making every "a" bold. I don't understand it. It's baffling me and I can't figure out why it's doing this.

I have turned off editors and checked to make sure nothing was interfering with code input but it's only happening on these 2 articles.

Comment: Did you check third party plugins and templates? Maybe they are the reason. Switch to different template, disable third party plugins one by one to see what extension causes this.

Comment: No, we can't help without seeing the code. Please link to your site if you want someone to give you the answer.

Comment: and a link to these 2 articles could also help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit with the help of Hung Tran. It was the Joomla! iseo plugin. After disabling it, everything works fine. Seth, thanks for your input.

Comment: Please accept your answer to mark it as solved